# Shuffle Files In A Dir With Sox (Endlesssly)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sox

I have a directory full of mp3s - /home/pi/Desktop/Music - and I want to be able to shuffle all the songs in the dir, so when I use sox to convert them into wma files on-the-fly, they will all be shuffled, and it will endlessly play through all the files in a andom order.
My current command is:

```
sox -R -t mp3 /home/pi/Desktop/Music/*.mp3 -t wav -r 44100 -
```

(The results get piped into pim):

```
sox -R -t mp3 /home/pi/Desktop/Music/*.mp3 -t wav -r 44100 - | sudo ./pi_fm_rds -freq 94.5  -audio - -ps ZSFM -rt ZSFM
```

How can I shuffle all the files in this dir on-the-fly with sox?

Comment: Can a tune be played times or not? Is the list truly randomised?

Comment: @JeremyBoden I just want it to play orever, and also play the songs in a random order (like not a whole album one song after another).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sox -R -t mp3 $(ls -1 /home/pi/Desktop/Music/*.mp3|sort -R) -t wav -r 44100 -
```

Comment: When I run that I get this:  sox WARN getopt: option `A' not recognized
sox FAIL sox: invalid option
What does it mean? I have no idea what option A is, and can't find anyhting about it anywhere.

Comment: igured it out, I had to remove the whitespace from the filenames (like turn dasa_berta/mp3 to dasa-berta.mp3). Thanks!